# How can I mock a property setter in NSubstitute

Tags: .net, vb.net, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

Here is what I tried doing:

```vb
    Public Interface IDAO(Of T) : Inherits IDAO
        Default Property Value(i As ULong) As T
        Function Append(ts As ICollection(Of T)) As ULong
        Function Remove(f As Predicate(Of T)) As ICollection(Of T)
        Function GetRestricted(f As Predicate(Of T)) As ICollection(Of T)
        Function RemoveFirst(f As Predicate(Of T)) As T
        Function GetFirst(f As Predicate(Of T)) As T
    End Interface
'...
_mock.WhenForAnyArgs(
    Function(mock As IDAO(Of T)) mock.Value(Arg.Any(Of ULong)) = Arg.Any(Of T)()
).Do(
    Sub(c As Core.CallInfo) Exit Sub 'Value(i) ... Set(v) ... _inner.data(i) = v                                                                                                 
)
```

The pattern selector `Function(mock As IDAO(Of T)) mock.Value(Arg.Any(Of ULong)) = Arg.Any(Of T)()` does not work; and even if it did I have no clue how I would utilise the `CallInfo` object in the `Do` statement.

Comment: FYI the strange `Enum Void` and `null As Void` are so that I can do pattern selection on methods that would ordinerily not be selectable and not allow a `Do` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure on how to do this in VB, but here is how to do it in C# and hopefully you or another person can translate.

```
    public interface IDao
    {
        ulong Value { get; set; }
    }

    [SuppressMessage("Argument specification", "NS3002:Can not find an argument to this call.", Justification = "Used in property set")]
    [Fact]
    public void PropertySetExample() {
        var sub = Substitute.For<IDao>();
        var value = 0ul;
        sub.WhenForAnyArgs(x => x.Value = 0ul).Do(callInfo =>
          // This will be called when sub.Value is set. 
          // For this example we just assign to a local variable.
          value = callInfo.Arg<ulong>()
        );

        sub.Value = 42;

        Assert.Equal(42ul, value);
    }
```

(The `SuppressMessage` is only required for [NSubstitute.Analyzers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/nsubstitute-analysers/) as it is not sure about the arguments to the property set.)

Comment: thank you for the answer, but what happens when the property requires arguments `x.prop(...) = ...`? Im not sure how to navigate callInfo in this case.

Comment: If there are args to a property of different types `A` and `B`, you can access as `callInfo.Arg<A>()` and `callInfo.Arg<B>()`. If there are args with the same types, you can access them via `callInfo.ArgAt<T>(index)`, or using `callInfo[index]` and cast to the right type. You can also access all arguments via `callInfo.Args()`.